# Use non native cordova plugin in Ionic 3

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I am trying to use the below cordova plugin for an Ionic 3 app. I have tried to access the plugin using window.plugins or cordova.plugins but none of them are working
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-touch-id

There are couple of similar questions being asked but their solution is not working. 
Can anyone let me know how can I use non native cordova plugin in Ionic 3

**Steps I followed**

1. ionic cordova plugin add
2. use `declare var cordova`
3. call the plugin when platform is ready using `cordova.plugins.<pluginname>`

Comment: _not working_... What are you getting? any errors? console logs etc...

Comment: Please make sure your code is in `platform.ready()` or `deviceready`. Usage `window.plugins.touchid....`.

Comment: @SurajRao if I do `console.log(window.plugins.touchid)` or `console.log(cordova.plugins.touchid)` I am getting undefined error

Comment: are you accessing within `this.platform.ready().then`?

Comment: @SurajRao, yes I am doing that..do I need to use cordova.plugins or window.plugins?

Comment: From [plugin.xml](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-touch-id/blob/master/plugin.xml#L27) its `window.plugins`

Comment: do I need to do anything apart from the steps I mentioned above?

Comment: are you trying in a device which supports this?

Comment: @SurajRao ok, just for the testing I have added another plugin https://github.com/mjwheatley/cordova-plugin-android-fingerprint-auth, since I am using android, I tried using `console.log("hello", FingerprintAuth)` but it gives an error saying undefined

Comment: did you refer this link : https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/touch-id/ ?

Comment: @CodeChanger, thanks for pointing to this, will take a look